# Is it possible to fetch data from Excel file with a descriptive script ? Coded UI C#

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

Here is my script..

```
// 3.Enter value into fields

//Firstname
 UITestControl objfirstname = new UITestControl(browser);
 objfirstname.TechnologyName = "Web";
 objfirstname.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "firstname");
 objfirstname.SetProperty("Text", "Shobhit");

 //Lastname
 UITestControl objlastname = new UITestControl(browser);
 objlastname.TechnologyName = "Web";
 objlastname.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "lastname");
 objlastname.SetProperty("Text", "Talwar");

//Email
 UITestControl objemail = new UITestControl(browser);
 objemail.TechnologyName = "Web";
 objemail.SearchProperties.Add("Name", "email");
 objemail.SetProperty("Text", "emailaddress");
```

As I am hardcoding the values. I want to know if there is any way to data drive these values from .xls or something.

Answer (score 0):

you can derive such values from couple of data sources including csv, xml etc.

example from MSDN

```
    [DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.CSV", "|DataDirectory|\\data.csv", "data#csv", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), DeploymentItem("data.csv"), TestMethod]
    public void CodedUITestMethod1()
    {

        // To generate code for this test, select "Generate Code for Coded UI Test" from the shortcut menu and select one of the menu items.
        this.UIMap.AddNumbers();
        this.UIMap.ValidateSum();

    }
```

more on [Creating a Data-Driven Coded UI Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624082.aspx)

also see [Building Data-Driven Coded UI Tests (CUIT) Using A CSV File](http://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2012/10/13/building-data-driven-coded-ui-tests-cuit-using-a-csv-file/)